# How to solve 'AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'' from subprocess.run()

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I am creating a bash script which calls a python script that in turn runs other processes in bash using `subprocess.run()`. However, when the bash script runs the python script within it, in the line where subprocess.run is called, I get an error message:

```
    run_metric = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines = True)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'
```

1) I made sure I ran the script using python 3 by activating a conda environment with python=3.6, which should not bring me any problem to call subprocess.run. The interesting thing is that if I change subprocess.run() to subprocess.Popen() the script works, but I could not work out how to get `run_metric.stdout` properly.

2) I do not have any subprocess.py file within any directory I am working in

3) the result of `print(subprocess.__file__)` is showing me that python is not 3.6: `/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc`

Also, I tried to use something like 
`from subprocess import run`
and making sure in both the python script and the function I had `import subprocess`

The bash script is as follows:

```sh
SWC_FOLDER_PATH=$(pwd)

sudo chmod +x /media/leandroscholz/KINGSTON/Results_article/Tracing_data/run_metrics.py 

echo "run /media/leandroscholz/Tracing_data/run_metrics.py ${SWC_FOLDER_PATH} /media/leandroscholz/KINGSTON/Results_article/TREEStoolbox_tree_fixed.swc"
python /media/leandroscholz/Tracing_data/run_metrics.py ${SWC_FOLDER_PATH} /media/leandroscholz/TREEStoolbox_tree_fixed.swc
```

And the python script I run calls a certain function that uses `subprocess.run()` this way (just part of the code where the problem arises):

```
import subprocess 
import glob

import numpy as np

def compute_metrics(swc_folder_path, gt_file_path):

    # first get list of files in swc_folder_path 
    swc_files = (glob.glob(swc_folder_path+"/*_fixed.swc"))
    n_swc_files = len(swc_files)

    workflow_dict = gets_workflow_dict(swc_files)
    n_images = get_n_images(swc_files)
    n_workflows = len(workflow_dict)

    for swc in range(0,n_swc_files):

        command = "java -jar /home/leandroscholz/DiademMetric.jar -G " + swc_files[swc] +" -T " + gt_file_path
        run_metric = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines = True)
```

I am using subprocess.run within python because, in the end, I want to get a string of the run_metric.stdout after running the process in bash so I can later store it in an array and save it to a txt file.

I hope I was sufficiently clear and provided enough information. 
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a file named `subprocess.py` or `subprocess.pyc` in the current directory?

Comment: What output do you get from this: `print (subprocess.__file__)`

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I've found that subprocess.__file__ is throwing a python 2 version, thus subprocess will not work. how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

After the comments received, I tested the output of `print(subprocess.__file__)`, which showed that python being used was python2.7,

Thus, I changed the call of the python script from `python script.py` to `python3 script.py`. I've found this question, which also shows another way to call python programs from terminal.

[Running Python File in Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244378/running-python-file-in-terminal)